# Mergesort Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I've tried to write a Mergesort Algorithm in Java:

```
static void merge(int[] sort, int l, int m, int r) {
    int[] cache_array = new int[r - l + 1];
    int l_cache = l;
    int _mid = m + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < r - l + 1; i++) {
        if (l > m) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[_mid];
            _mid++;
        } else { if (_mid > r) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[l];
            l++;
        } else { if (sort[l] >= sort[_mid]) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[l];
            l++;
        } else { if (sort[_mid] > sort[l]) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[_mid];
            _mid++;
        }}}}
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cache_array.length; i++) {
        sort[i + l_cache] = cache_array[i];
    }
}

static void mergeSort(int[] sort, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int mid = (int)Math.floor((l + r - 1) / 2);
        mergeSort(sort, l, mid);
        mergeSort(sort, mid + 1, r);
        merge(sort, l, mid, r);
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 2, 1, 4, 5, 73, 74, 7, 5, 64, 2 };
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

But it just sorts a part of the Array and replaces the rest of it with zeros. I tried to change the cache_array to a LinkedList but nothing changed and after I tried debugging I couldn't find out anything, too.
I'd appreciate it if you'd help me and/or show me another Mergesort Algorithm that works for Java.
(I used this Algorithm because it worked for Python and so I wanted to use similar code in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in your code is difficult to spot:

- the loop in your `merge` function iterates for `i` from `0` to `r - l + 1` excluded, which would be correct if `r` and `l` remained constant during the loop, but you increment `l` each time you copy from the left part, reducing the number of iterations. As a consequence, the loop exits early, leaving the remaining elements in `cache_array` with their default value `0`.

There are multiple sources of confusion in the code:

- the convention to include `r` in the slice is confusing: it requires `+1`/`-1` adjustments to compute the slice lengths and the middle index.
- using `Math.floor()` is useless: integer arithmetic uses integer division in java.
- incrementing the `l` and `m` arguments is confusing as these lose their meaning if the value is changed. Use other index variables to iterate through the arrays.
- adding a `{` between the `else` and `if` keywords introduces unnecessary indentation levels.
- the last condition is the opposite of the previous one: you should just omit it. Note that if the array elements were floating point values, both conditions could be false for NaN values and some elements of `cache_array` would be left untouched. This last condition would cause errors in this case.

Here is a modified version:

```java
// merge adjacent slices of the `sort` array.
// left slice has elements from `l` included to `m` excluded
// right slice has elements from `m` included to `r` excluded
static void merge(int[] sort, int l, int m, int r) {
    int len = r - l;
    int[] cache_array = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0, ll = l, mm = m; i < len; i++) {
        if (ll >= m) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[mm];
            mm++;
        } else
        if (mm >= r) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[ll];
            ll++;
        } else
        if (sort[ll] >= sort[mm]) {
            cache_array[i] = sort[ll];
            ll++;
        } else {
            cache_array[i] = sort[mm];
            mm++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sort[l + i] = cache_array[i];
    }
}

static void mergeSort(int[] sort, int l, int r) {
    if (r - l > 1) {
        int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(sort, l, mid);
        mergeSort(sort, mid, r);
        merge(sort, l, mid, r);
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 2, 1, 4, 5, 73, 74, 7, 5, 64, 2 };
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.length);
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer in detail. I could correct the code and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I write the mergesort algorithm.

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] sort) {
    if(sort.length > 1) {
        int mid = sort.length / 2;
        int[] left = Arrays.copyOf(sort, mid);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(sort, mid, sort.length);

        // sort the left and right arrays
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        // Merge the arrays
        merge(sort, left, right);
    }
}

private static void merge(int[] sort, int[] leftArray, int[] rightArray) {
    // These values are just to keep track of our position in each of the 3 
    // arrays
    int l = 0; // left array
    int r = 0; // right array
    int o = 0; // the actual array being sorted

    while(l < leftArray.length && r < rightArray.length) {
        if(leftArray[l] < righArray[r]) {
            sort[o++] = leftArray[l++];
        }
        else {
            sort[o++] = leftArray[r++];
        }
    }

    // Now that we are out of the while loop we know that either the 
    // left or right array has all of its values in sort, so we just 
    // need to put the rest of the values in the array that doesn't have
    // all of its elements in sort with the following code.

    while(l < leftArray.length) {
        sort[o++] = leftArray[l++];
    }

    while(r < rightArray.length) {
        sort[o++] = rightArray[r++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your proposal does not help the OP identify the error in his code. Furthermore, your code attempts to sort the array in ascending order whereas the OP's sorts it in descending order.

Comment: The prototype for your `mergeSort` should be `public static void mergeSort(int[] sort)` or you should return `sort`.  Also the `else` branch of the `if` statement in `merge` should copy from `rightArray`, not `leftArray`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Mergesort
/// best-case: O(n* log(n))
/// average-case: O(n* log(n))
/// worst-case: O(n* log(n))
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The sorted array.</returns>
/// <param name="array">array.</param>
public static int[] MergeSort(int[] array) {
        //  Exit condition for recursion
        if (array.length <= 1) return array;
        //  Middle index of list to sort
        int m = array.length / 2;
        //  Define left and right sub-listså
        int[] left_array = new int[m];
        int[] right_array = new int[array.length - m];
        //  Initialize left list
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) left_array[i] = array[i];
        //  Initialize right list
        for (int i = m, x = 0; i < array.length; i++, x++) right_array[x] = array[i];
        //  Recursively sort left half of the list
        left_array = MergeSort(left_array);
        //  Recursively sort right half of the list
        right_array = MergeSort(right_array);
        //  Merge sorted sub-lists
        return Merge(left_array, right_array);
}
/// <summary>
/// Merge the specified left_array and right_array.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The merge.</returns>
/// <param name="left_array">Left array.</param>
/// <param name="right_array">Right array.</param>
public static int[] Merge(int[] left_array, int[] right_array) {
        int[] m = new int[left_array.length + right_array.length];
        int index_l = 0;
        int nl, nr;
        nl = left_array.length - 1;
        nr = right_array.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= nl + nr + 1; i++) {
                if (index_l > nl) {
                        m[i] = (right_array[i - index_l]);
                        continue;
                }
                if (index_l < i - nr) {
                        m[i] = (left_array[index_l]);
                        index_l++;
                        continue;
                }
                if (left_array[index_l] <= (right_array[i - index_l])) {
                        m[i] = (left_array[index_l]);
                        index_l++;
                } else {
                        m[i] = (right_array[i - index_l]);
                }
        }
        return m;
}
```

A few months ago I wrote all of the common sorting algorithms and this is what I got. A bit inaccurate but just to See how this implementation performs.
[The other algorithms are here.](https://github.com/SchnJulian/Sorting-Algorithms-CSharp-Java)

**To achieve a descending order I think you just have to swap the comparison operators.**

[image: Benchmark]

Comment: Your code implements a different approach: the OP's sorts the array in place whereas your code produces a new sorted array and leaves to original array untouched, **except** for arrays with a single or no element. Note also that your approach requires **O(N.log(N))** extra space, which is unnecessary. **O(N)** extra space should suffice.

Comment: Oh then ill take my answer back!